# Fatal Error upgrading Adobe Director Movie from Version 10 to 11.5

Tags: fatal-error, adobe-director

So, i'm loading an old project to do some updates. The project has been upgraded a few times in the past without issue. However, upgrading to 11.5 is producing the dreaded error: A Fatal Error Has Occurred. Click OK to Quit.

The next screen produces MS C++ Runtime Error:

Runtime Error!
The app has ... terminated in unusual way... Please contact support team ...

Completely useless error so i'm wondering if anyone has discovered common causes. This project does have an old 3rd party Xtra called MasterApp. However, all the other casts and .dir files upgrade fine when using this Xtra. The only thing unique about the files that fail is they are both over 200mb.

Answer (score 0):

since the error message of director does not help, I would suggest you to try these things to narrow the error:

-Open the files in Director 10 an copy all Cast Members etc into a new file. Try if that helped.

-Remove the xtra fro the files and see if that helps. If it helps, than try to replace - for example by the BudApi-Xtra.

-Does your casts have big media which are not images? Sounds oder Videos for example? I would suggest lokking at them first.

-Try to convert the files on a windows PC.

BTW: Do you have the latest version of D11.5? MayBe there is an update that you can install.

Regards

Arno

Comment: I do. And we also tried to get around the issue by upgrading to V12. V12 produces the same error. Thank you for the ideas. I will try to narrow it down further.